# How to restrict Lagrange multiplier on positive values?

Tags: calculus, functions, derivatives, lagrange-multiplier

Here's the function that i want to optimize:

$$f(x,y) = x-2y$$

and the constraint is:

$$g(x,y) = x^2 + y - 10 = 0$$

Solving with Lagrange multiplier I get:

$$F(x,y,\lambda) = x-2y - x^2\lambda - y\lambda + 10\lambda$$

$$F_x = 1 - 2x\lambda = 0$$
$$F_y = -2-\lambda = 0 \iff \lambda = -2 $$
$$F_\lambda = x^2 + y - 10 = 0$$

Then:

$$1+4x = 0$$
$$4x = -1$$
$$x = -\frac 14$$

$$\frac1{16} + y - 10 = 0$$
$$y = \frac{159}{16}$$

So I found one stationary point and obviously it's the minimum of the function and it's:

$$f(-\frac{1}{4},\frac{159}{16}) = -20,125$$

At these conditions this function doesn't have maximum, but if we restrict x and y only to positive values we should be able to obtain one. How can we do that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You want to maximize the function $f(x,y)=x-2y$ on the part of the parabola $y=10-x^2$ within the first quadrant.  Substituting we have the function $f(x,10-x^2)=2x^2+x-20$, and we are only considering values of $x$ from $0$ to $\sqrt{10}$.  You've already shown there is no local extrema within these values, so we only check the endpoints.  $f(0,10)=-20$ and $f(\sqrt{10},0)=\sqrt{10}$, so we have a maximum of $\sqrt{10}$ at $(\sqrt{10},0)$.

Suppose instead we were trying to optimize the function $f(x,y,z)=x-2y+z$ on the sphere $x^2+y^2+z^2=1$, but we only wanted to consider points in the first octant.  Call this part of the sphere $S$.  First, we would apply Lagrange to see if there are any local extrema on $S$.  Then, we would need to consider the boundary of $S$, which consists of three quarter arcs.  Let's only work with the arc specified by the constraint $x^2+y^2=1$ for $x$ and $y$ positive (note we've set $z=0$).  Hence, now we are trying to optimize $f(x,y,0)=x-2y$ on $x^2+y^2=1$, for $x$ and $y$ positive.  Again, we apply Lagrange to search for local extrema, and then check the boundary, which in this case is just two points.

After checking all three boundary arcs, along with the points defining the boundaries of the arcs, we collect all of our values (local extrema as well as the boundary values) and find the largest and smallest.

In general, this is how you search for global extrema on a closed region.

Comment: So there isn't a direct way to include that restriction in Lagrange multiplier, because if we have 3 variable or more complex constraint this would be much more difficult.

Comment: @Stefan4024: In general, you use Lagrange multipliers to compute local extrema.  If the local extrema do not fall within your desired region, then to find global extrema, you check the boundary.  In this case, the boundary was just two points, so it would be strange to use Lagrange, however, in higher dimensional questions, the boundary itself might be a curve or a surface, in which case another application of Lagrange would be appropriate to yield global maxima and minima.  I'll try to include a brief example in my answer.

Comment: One last question, you said that we set $z=0$, then x and y and we collect values and compare them. $x^2 + y^2 + z^2 = 1$ is equation for sphere. Will the same method work for some unothodox constrain let's say $x^2 + y + z^3 = 1$ or $abc = 1$

Comment: @Stefan4024: Yes, it should work.  This is because the intersection of the plane $z=0$ (which is a boundary of the first octant) with the equation of your constraint (no matter what it is) should give you a curve in the $xy$-plane which represents the boundary of the closed region along the $xy$-plane.  In the case of the surface you wrote down, this curve will be $x^2+y=1$.  Notice that the region $xyz=1$ in the first octant has no boundary, and so we can only look for local extrema.

Comment: Tnx mate. You made some things clearer to me.